# Legend for color-coded table in R

Tags: r, legend, gt

I've created a color-coded table in R's gt package with conditional formatting. I would like to include something that will function as a legend to signify what the colors mean. For instance (for simplicity):

```r
a <- c(1 , 3 , 5 , 9)
b <- c(1 , 2 , 6 , 10)
ab <- data.frame(a , b)

library(gt)

gt(ab) %>%
  tab_style(style = list(cell_fill(color = '#E69F00') ,
                         cell_text(weight = 'bold')) ,
            locations = cells_body(columns = vars(a) ,
                                   rows = (a > b)))
```

This produces an example of the color-coded table. I'd like to have a notation in source notes or a location below the figures that that would reproduce the color and indicate in text that the colored cell meant that a was higher than b. Any help or referral appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I poked around and found an answer. I'm sure more experienced coders could find something better, but adding html instructions to a tab_source_note worked for me. It's just proof of concept; I can change font size to make it nicer. Passing it on in case someone else has this challenge.

```r
a <- c(1 , 3 , 5 , 9)
b <- c(1 , 2 , 6 , 10)
ab <- data.frame(a , b)

library(gt)
#> Warning: package 'gt' was built under R version 3.6.3

gt(ab) %>%
  tab_style(style = list(cell_fill(color = '#E69F00') , 
                         cell_text(weight = 'bold')) , 
            locations = cells_body(columns = vars(a) , 
                                   rows = (a > b))) %>%
  tab_source_note(html('<pre><span style="background-color: #E69F00;"
                       >        </span> = Higher</pre>'))
```